# Jython ziclix JDBC, get stored procedure return value - Chained Transaction Mode

Tags: stored-procedures, jdbc, jython, sybase

I am trying to get value returned by a Sybase user-defined stored procedure, following is the code snippet.

```
from com.ziclix.python.sql import zxJDBC

def callStoredProc(conn, procName, *args):
    conn.execute("USE DB")
    sql = """DECLARE @ret int
             EXEC @ret = %s %s
             SELECT @ret""" % (procName, ','.join(['?'] * len(args)))
    return int(conn.execute(sql, args).fetchone()[0])

jdbc_url  = "jdbc:sybase:Tds:192.168.1.100:3397/stagingdb"
username  = "sa"
password  = ""
driver    = "com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver"
conn      = zxJDBC.connect(jdbc_url, username, password, driver)
cursor = conn.cursor()

print callStoredProc(cursor, "usp_find", "Apples" )
```

But when I run script, it says;

> zxJDBC.Error: Stored procedure 'usp_find' may be run only in unchained transaction mode. The 'SET CHAINED OFF' command will cause the current session to use unchained transaction mode. [SQLCode: 7713], [SQLState: ZZZZZ]

However, if I add `conn.execute("SET CHAINED OFF")` in `callStoredProc()` it return `None`.

Is there any way to get returned value off sybase stored procedure in Jython/Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how to change chainde transation mode, but I want you to try "clear" JDBC and CallableStatemet. Such code looks like (I do not have Sybase so I cannot test it):

```
db = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, usr, passwd)
proc = db.prepareCall("{ ? = call usp_find(?) }");
proc.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER)
proc.setString(2, "Apples");
proc.execute();
r = proc.getInt(1)
print('result: %d' % (r))
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it worked. I just want to add few more lines for a newbie like me;

from java.sql  import DriverManager
import java.sql.Types as types 

db = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sybase:Tds:192.168.1.100:3397/stagingdb", "sa", "")

and then almost all the lines.

The right syntax will depends upon how the user-defined stored-procedure is written, in this regard I have to mold my actual problem a bit, sp_helptext was helpful as well.